# What is the parameter for dht nodes in magnet-links?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, magnet-uri

There is nothing on this neither in [DHT BEP](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) nor in [magnet links BEP](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0053.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any client supporting such a flag. But there is one (`x.pe`) to embed addresses bittorrent peers, which in turn can signal their DHT port with the PORT message.
Clients are assumed to already have bootstrapepd a DHT node when using magnet links that don't contain trackers or fixed peer addresses.